# Optimizing a numpy calculation for an audio DSP program

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, signal-processing

I'm a musician and I'm writing a python script that reads a .wav file, uses the fast fourier transform to turn it into a bunch of sine waves, then tunes those sine waves to their nearest harmonic frequency. If all of that sounded like gibberish then that's fine, my question can be answered without any music knowledge.

When I run my script on a fairly long .wav file it takes several hours to process the following section of the script:

```
filtered_data_fft = np.zeros(data_fft.size)
for f in data_fft:
    if f > 1:
        valid_frequency = (np.abs(valid_frequencies - i)).argmin()
        filtered_data_fft[valid_frequency] += data_fft[i]
    i += 1
```

Both of the arrays that end with fft are arrays where the index corresponds to a frequency, and the valid_frequencies array is a list of frequencies that correspond to said indices. I originally didn't use numpy arrays for everything and it took so long to run that I couldn't get a short sound file to process in a reasonable time, but with numpy it's a lot faster. Can anyone think of a way to make it even faster than this? I'll put the full script below.

Also, there are two known warnings about casting complex values to real ones which discards the complex number, but I don't think they're a problem. The FFT returns an array of tuples where the first value is a frequency and the second one is a complex number that represents something I don't quite understand, but according to the page I followed to learn this it's not important. Here's where I learned this stuff: https://pythonforengineers.com/audio-and-digital-signal-processingdsp-in-python/

Admittedly I don't fully understand a lot of the DSP stuff I'm doing here, so let me know if I'm horribly wrong about something! I'm just trying to make an interesting way to turn noise into music for a project I'm working on.

Here's the audio sample I'm testing with:
https://my.mixtape.moe/iltlos.wav
(rename it to missile.wav)

And here's the full script (updated to be correct):

```
import struct
import wave
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# import data from wave
wav_file = wave.open("missile.wav", 'r')
num_samples = wav_file.getnframes()
sampling_rate = wav_file.getframerate() / 2
data = wav_file.readframes(num_samples)
wav_file.close()

data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=num_samples), data)
data = np.array(data)

# fast fourier transform makes an array of the frequencies of sine waves that comprise the sound
data_fft = np.fft.rfft(data)


# generate list of ratios that can be used for tuning (not octave reduced)
MAX_HARMONIC = 5
valid_ratios = []
for i in range(1, MAX_HARMONIC + 1):
    for j in range(1, MAX_HARMONIC + 1):
        if i % 2 != 0 and j % 2 != 0:
            valid_ratios.append(i/float(j))
            valid_ratios.append(j/float(i))


# remove dupes
valid_ratios = list(set(valid_ratios))


# find all the frequencies with the valid ratios
valid_frequencies = []
multiple = 2
while(multiple < num_samples / 2):
    multiple *= 2

    for ratio in valid_ratios:
        frequency = ratio * multiple

        if frequency < num_samples / 2:
            valid_frequencies.append(frequency)



# remove dupes and sort and turn into a numpy array
valid_frequencies = np.sort(np.array(list(set(valid_frequencies))))


# bin the data_fft into the nearest valid frequency
valid_frequencies = valid_frequencies.astype(int)
boundaries = np.concatenate([[0], np.round(np.sqrt(0.25 + valid_frequencies[:-1] * valid_frequencies[1:])).astype(int)])
select = np.abs(data_fft) > 1
filtered_data_fft = np.zeros_like(data_fft)
filtered_data_fft[valid_frequencies] = np.add.reduceat(np.where(select, data_fft, 0), boundaries)


# do the inverse fourier transform to get a sound wave back
recovered_signal = np.fft.irfft(filtered_data_fft)

# write sound wave to wave file
comptype="NONE"
compname="not compressed"
nchannels=1
sampwidth=2

wav_file=wave.open("missile_output.wav", 'w')
wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, int(sampling_rate), num_samples, comptype, compname))

for s in recovered_signal:
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', s))

wav_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes on your script:

(1) Since you are using `rfft`, the matching inverse would be `irfft` not `ifft`

(2) As it stands the script accepts *every* frequency except `0` as valid (because `1` is included in `valid_ratios`

(3) The complex number at a given frequency contains the amplitude and the phase (shift) of that "sine wave". I'm assuming you want to filter based on the amplitude. For that you have to take the absolute value of the complex number, i.e. `np.abs(f) > 1` etc.

(4) Once you have a good set of valid frequencies you can proceed as follows. I'm going with @Mateen Ulhaq's suggestion of using geometric midpoints.

```
boundaries = np.concatenate([[0], np.round(np.sqrt(0.25 + valid_frequencies[:-1] * valid_frequencies[1:])).astype(int)])
select = np.abs(data_fft) > 1
filtered_data_fft = np.zeros_like(data_fft)
filtered_data_fft[valid_frequencies] = np.add.reduceat(np.where(select, data_fft, 0), boundaries)
```

Comment: I get an error at the beginning of the last line you wrote
    filtered_data_fft[valid_frequencies]
because valid_frequencies isn't an array of bools, how can I convert the list of frequencies to a list of bools where all the trues are at the index numbers of the valid frequencies?

Comment: Here's the updated way of finding the frequencies, I was doing it totally wrong
https://paste.ee/p/TgDju

Comment: @halbe Could you please try `valid_frequencies = valid_frequencies.astype(int)`? That should work.

Comment: Like this? https://paste.ee/p/LIt6P
I get this error now: IndexError: index 74316 out-of-bounds in add.reduceat [0, 74305)

Comment: @halbe that is because the output of rfft is cut at Nyquist (which happens to be a good idea, anyway), you can check it's half the size of the input. In the block where you compute `valid_frequencies` replace both occurrences of `num_samples` with `num_samples // 2`.

Comment: It works, and it's very fast. Thanks! Now I need to find a way to slowly tune one frequency at a time so a sound is "harmonized" over time. Would it be best to make a separate question for this?

Comment: @halbe yes, it should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to bin or digitize your data. Start by defining your decision boundaries:

```
valid_frequencies = np.sort(valid_frequencies)
b = valid_frequencies
b = (b[1:] + b[:-1]) / 2
bins = np.concatenate(([0], b, [MAX_FREQ]))
```

Though you might find more success if you use a geometric mean rather than arithmetic mean. (Frequency analysis is usually more of a log based thing.)

```
b = np.sqrt(b[1:] * b[:-1])
```

Now you simply digitize your data, then perform a count of the appearances of the various indices:

```
hist = np.bincount(np.digitize(data_fft, bins))[1:]
```

Perhaps even faster is:

```
hist = np.histogram(data_fft, bins=bins)[0]
```

Finally, we embed these at the correct indices:

```
filtered_data_fft = np.zeros_like(data_fft)
filtered_data_fft[valid_frequencies] = hist
```

---

**EDIT:** For example,

```
>>> data_fft = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9])
>>> valid_frequencies = np.sort([2, 4])

>>> b = valid_frequencies
>>> b = (b[1:] + b[:-1]) / 2
>>> bins = np.concatenate(([0.0], b, [10.0]))
array([ 0.,  3., 10.])

>>> hist = np.bincount(np.digitize(data_fft, bins))[1:]
array([2, 7])

>>> hist = np.histogram(data_fft, bins=bins)[0]
array([2, 7])

>>> filtered_data_fft = np.zeros(11)
>>> filtered_data_fft[valid_frequencies] = hist
array([0., 0., 2., 0., 7., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: It processes much faster but the output is all zeroes, did I miss something? https://paste.ee/p/TbNoT

Comment: @halbe I suppose you need to be wary that `np.bincount()` outputs an extra `0` at the beginning. I've sliced it off above with `[1:]`. Also make sure that `num_samples` is indeed your maximum frequency. Or consider using `np.histogram` since that seems to handle these edge cases a bit better.

Comment: The filtered_data_fft needs to be the same size as data_fft, its values are volumes and the frequencies are the index positions. So 440hz is at the index 440 whose value is the volume of the 440hz sine wave, but in the valid_frequencies array there is a value 440 at an arbitrary position.

Comment: @halbe That was trickier than I thought. Anyways, I've updated the answer.

Comment: In your example the filtered array should be [0., 6.6, 0., 42.9, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]) because the first two or three frequencies (rounding) should add their volumes to the second bin (there is no frequency of 0), and the rest should be added to the fourth bin because it is the closest one. Right now its adding up the number of frequencies that were binned, not the volume of those frequencies. Otherwise it's quite close though! How could I bin the values?

Comment: @halbe Ah, in that case, you should probably go with Paul's suggestion. :P